# XML applescript

Tags: xml, applescript, weather

I know there are loads of threads with titles like this but I'm new to applescript and I don't understand them. Basically I want to take [this](http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=NewYork&mode=xml) XML http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=NewYork&mode=xml
and then put the values like temperature and wind speed into their own variable so I can do what ever I want with them. 
Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should post the code you have so far, otherwise it looks like you know no coding and are just asking someone to do work for you.
You have two choices. One is to use one of a few XML parsing options. But for some applications of small XML files like you have on the openweathermap site, is to just hard code the delimiters to pull what you want. This works for what you've asked:

```
set xmlString to do shell script "curl 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=NewYork&mode=xml'"

set otid to AppleScript's text item delimiters

set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "<temperature value=\""
set xmlString to text item 2 of xmlString
set theTemp to word 1 of xmlString

set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "<speed value=\""
set xmlString to text item 2 of xmlString
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "\""
set theSpeed to text item 1 of xmlString

set AppleScript's text item delimiters to otid

return "Temperature is " & theTemp & " & Speed is " & theSpeed
```

Comment: You don’t have to use shell scripting to work with XML in AppleScript because it can do it natively, and you don’t have to parse it as text because AppleScript is object-oriented, and you definitely don’t want to do that parsing with text item delimiters because the reason AppleScript doesn’t have built-in text handling is there are AppleScriptable text editors with which you can handle text.